# syntax error when launching java script web project

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I have a table that is being populated by firebase database values. When I launch the application, I obtain the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app.js' does not provide an export named 'child'
at (program)

Can someone provide a solution

HTML and JS code

```
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    
    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        var id = 0;
        var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody1');
        function addItem(First_Name, Last_Name, Password, Phone_Number, Email, Account_Status) {
            let trow = document.createElement("tr");
            let td1 = document.createElement('td');
            let td2 = document.createElement('td');
            let td3 = document.createElement('td');
            let td4 = document.createElement('td');
            let td5 = document.createElement('td');
            let td6 = document.createElement('td');

            td1.innerHTML = First_Name;
            td2.innerHTML = Last_Name;
            td3.innerHTML = Password;
            td4.innerHTML = Phone_Number;
            td5.innerHTML = Email;
            td6.innerHTML = Account_Status;

            trow.appendChild(td1);
            trow.appendChild(td2);
            trow.appendChild(td3);
            trow.appendChild(td4);
            trow.appendChild(td5);
            trow.appendChild(td6);

            tbody.appendChild(trow);
        }

        function AddAllItemsToTable(users) {
            tbody.innerHTML = "";
            users.forEach(element => {
                addItem(element.First_Name, element.Last_Name, element.Password, element.Phone_Number, element.Email, element.Account_Status);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Do NOT post your api CREDENTIALS onto the internet. These should be removed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to import the Realtime Database functions from the wrong SDK.

Change the import to:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-database.js";
```

So `firebase-database.js` instead of `firebase-app.js`.